# Angular update content based on checked radio

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i am using reactive forms, when you choose currency symbol on first row i want to update second rows cash amount and currency symbol, for every selected currency amount will change too, how can i do that? Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-r8hn18?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: There's no code on your stackblitz, you just given us the html template. Basically saying... "Here's the template code it for me". Not that we arn't willing to help, it just why would we put the effort in it when you don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Are your values for amount static ? (Is it always 25 - 50 - 75- 100k ?) If yes, then make them variable, or put it in some array and do `*ngFor` in template. Also, make some variable for currency which you are going to show in template as well instead of currency symbol. Then just subscribe to your formcontrol called currency of formGroup like this

```
this.formGroup.controls.currency.valueChanges(value => {
   if (value == 'EUR') {
      this.currencySymbol = '€';
      this.amountArray = this.amountArray.map(amount => amount * eurExchangeRate)
   }
}
```

In template just do

```
<div *ngFor="let amount of amountArray">
 <span>{{amount}}</span>
 <span>{{currencySymbol}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. i tried implementing your code but i dont get it and i am stuck. here is my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-r8hn18?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: also no amount isn't static, amount changes on currency change too